# Rewrite URL using htaccess from codeigniter routes with more than one paramater

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting, .htaccess

The example website is :

> "https://www.abcde.com"

also

**The example routes :**

> $route['home/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)']
>   = 'Admin_center/home/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$9/$10/$11';

When open the route page home, it will become like :

> "https://abcde.com/index.php/home/1/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/2/"

I want to hide all the paramater. It is for security reason. So it will become :

> "https://abcde.com/"

Or

> "https://abcde.com/index.php/home"

Both of them is allright for me.

Is there any way to do this with redirect using htaccess or codeigniter itself can do this ?

If yes, how to do this ?

Thank You